# ARM template to deploy vNet failing

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I'm using this arm template to deploy a vnet and 3 subnets but I keep getting an error message, can't quite work out whats wrong. I need to seperate the vnet into three subnets.

The Arm template is:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "vnetName": {
      "value": "vnet-west-europe"
    },
    "vnetAddressPrefix": {
      "value": "10.1.254.0/24"
    },
    "subnet1Prefix": {
      "value": "10.1.254.0/27"
    },
    "subnet1Name": {
      "value": "subnet1-west-europe"
    },
    "subnet2Prefix": {
      "value": "10.1.254.96/25"
    },
    "subnet2Name": {
      "value": "subnet3-west-europe"
    },
    "location": {
      "value": "west europe"
    },
    "subnet3Prefix": {
      "value": "10.1.254.32/26"
    },
    "subnet3Name": {
      "value": "subnet3-west-europe"
    }
  }
}
```

The error I get is

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment : 20:28:18 - Error: Code=InvalidCIDRNotation; Message=The address prefix 10.1.254.96/25 in resource /subscriptions/<SUB-ID>/resourceGroups/network-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-west-europe/subnets/subnet-west-europe has an invalid CIDR notation. For the given prefix length, the address prefix should be 10.1.254.0/25.
At line:1 char:1
```

But if I change it to the specified IP it overlaps with the subnet1

Help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CIDR in subnet2Prefix is incorrect: 10.1.254.96/25

It either needs to be `10.1.254.0/25` or `10.1.254.128/25` if you want it to be that long.

changing the layout will help you, with the largest subnet first or you can have a larger Address Prefix and put them on diffrent C blocks.

```
vnetAddressPrefix: 10.1.254.0/24
subnet1Prefix: 10.1.254.0/25
subnet2Prefix: 10.1.254.128/26
subnet3Prefix:10.1.254.192/27
```

Use this IP Calculator to verify your prefixes: http://jodies.de/ipcalc?host=10.1.254.128&mask1=25&mask2=